# Invalid Floating point operation using round(double) in Delphi

Tags: delphi, rounding

I am using Delphi 7, where I have variable v: double which is set to value 5,5889002873e+22 .

CurrencyDecimals is 2

When I use round(v), I get this error:

Invalid Floating point operation

It is not clear to me why it happens because range of double is exponent  -308 to +308 . How to perform the rounding to be correct?

Comment: Depending on your task, you may use `int` to get the integer part (without error because it returns a floating-point result).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Result of `Round` is integer variable ([help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Round))

```
function Round(X: Real): Int64;
```

but `Int64` type cannot contain values more than `2^63 - 1` (about `9*10^18`), so

> If the rounded value of X is not within the Int64 range, a run-time error is generated

What is a purpose of this rounding?

Comment: Thank you. I will add conditions to fix it.

Comment: You mean `round` instead of `random`.